# Disable Gesture Recognizer for UIImageView in iPad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uipagecontrol

I have a `PageControl` and each page (`ViewController`) has different number of `imageviews` (`UIImageView`), which are created dynamically.

Each `imageview` is assigned a `gesture recognizer (tapped or move)`. Since these are inside a `PageControl`, I would like to enable/disable the `gesture recognizer` so it won't interfere with the `swipe` to page events.

I know that there's a `removeGestureRecognizer` method, but I don't want to remove and attach that each time. Is there an equivalent for just enabling and disabling?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use enable or disable properties of the UIGestureRecognizer like :

```
swipeGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

or you can use the gesture recognizer method return **null**  if you don't want touches

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

Comment: thank you both. Both answers are correct, but since I'm creating them dynamically (no through the interface) I"m accepting this answer. But it's good to know the UI answer to that too for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable all the gestures at the same time, you can do like

```
imageView.userIntractionEnabled = NO;
```

if you want to disable only one gesture recognizer, then

```
NSArray *gestures = imageView.gestureRecognizers;
for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in gestures)
{
    if([gesture isKindOfClass: [UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        gesture.enabled = NO;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use dot syntax to send non-property messages.

Answer (score 1):

Can you disable `userInteractionEnabled` for that `UIImageView` ? You could do it in Interface Builder if you are doing it that way or you could programatically set this like so - `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` Hope this helps...

[image]

Comment: Great. thanks for the explanation and picture. That's a great reference to know, even though I'm doing it all dynamically in code.

Comment: cool. Its difficult to build everything in GUI for DEV. In any case you can disable `userInteraction` from code directly. `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` does this help ?